# minipages won't go next to each other, second one is displayed on next page

Tags: minipage

Good Morning,

i do have a seemingly very stupid error: I'm trying to build something quite similar to 20secondcv for my curriculum vitae, but for some reasons (getting more used to LaTeX in the first place) want to build it from scratch. I want to have a minipage for the left 'infobar'. I have used minipages before and thought it should be quite easy. Thing is, if i don't use a minipage for the right part, it seems to start somewhere in the last third of my page for one row, and then continue on the next page. [Click here for the example](https://www.overleaf.com/9444307xpjgcgpxrmxz#/34180047/) This seems already really really strange to me, i would be happy if someone could explain it to me. 
The next thing is, that when i use minipages for both of them, the right one is put onto the next page, even if i set both their width on 0.2 textwidth. This is again really really strange. [Click me for this example](https://www.overleaf.com/9444356fxvcrtccqcpx#/34180272/) .

I feel like there is a really stupid mistake i made and just don't find it, but after searching and googling for some hour and not being successfull in any way, i come to you.

As not everyone is willing to click random links, i will put the last part of code, which is most important to me, here:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[left=0cm,right=0cm,top=1cm,bottom=0cm]{geometry}
\definecolor{sidebargrey}{HTML}{ECEDF3}
\newcommand{\infowidth}{0.23 \textwidth}
\begin{document}

\begin{flushleft}
\begin{minipage}[][\textheight][t]{0.2 \textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \fill [fill=sidebargrey] (-21,-40) rectangle (5,300);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \blindtext
    \blindtext
\end{minipage}
\end{flushleft}
\begin{flushright}
    \begin{minipage}[][\textheight][t]{0.7 \textwidth}
        \blindtext
    \end{minipage}
\end{flushright}

\end{document}
```

Thank you so much for your help in advance!

Comment: Remove the `flushleft` and `flushright` environments.

Comment: I started without them, but the part which is supposed to be on the right side is still on the next page.

Comment: There is no blank line allowed between the minipages.

Comment: Oh thank you so much! Stupid little mistakes :D

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in comments (unneeded spacing between minipage environments).